# Special forms of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67536/is-there-a-name-for-xx-1y1c-1c-2x-c-3yc-1c-2y-0), @Gerben suggested that it is more likely that WA recognizes an ODE in"Sturm-Liouville" form. Is there a reason for this particular form being preferred to the usual $a(x)y''+b(x)y'+c(x)y=0$ form?
Thanks.

(In particular, are the equations easier to solve in this form?)